# Find an interval inside an other interval using R

Tags: r, intervals

I am trying to find if a list of intervals is inside another list of intervals using R. For example:

list1

```
     start         end
     100           500
     700           800
```

list2

```
    start          end
    200            300
    800            850
```

The expected output would be

```
     TRUE
     FALSE
```

so I tried something like this:

```
        for (i in nrow(list1)){
          for (j in nrow(list2)){
            if ((list1[i, 1] <= list2[i,1]) & (list1[i, 2] >= list2[i,2])){
              print(list1[i, 1]) 
              }
            }
          }
```

But is not working. Also the two lists doesn't have the same length, and could be that several intervals of the second list would be in a single interval of the first list.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No need for a loop, R is vectorized: `dat$start < dat2$start & dat$end > dat2$end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `any` to see if the rows in `list2` are within any of the ranges defined in `list1`

```
sapply(1:NROW(list2), function(i)
    any(list2$start[i] > list1$start & list2$end[i] < list1$end))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

**DATA**

```
list1 = structure(list(start = c(100, 700), end = c(500, 800)), .Names = c("start", 
"end"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

list2 = structure(list(start = c(200, 800), end = c(300, 850)), .Names = c("start", 
"end"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```